# Volume of a region R when revolved about the x-axis

Tags: calculus, integration, volume

Find the volume of the region when revolved about the $x$ axis

$y= \sqrt{x-1}$, $y=2$, $y=0$, and $x=0$

[image: function]

Is this right?

[image: integral]

Also if you could help me with revolving this same region around $y=2$, and $x=5$, I would really appreciate it.

NOTE: The y=2, and x=5 are two separate questions, so in 1 question asked to revolve about y=2, and in the other anoe about x=5

Comment: It looks like you made your radius $\sqrt{x-1}$, but is that really the radius that we want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the problem and the graph you presented, your volume integral formula may be more like this:
$$V=\int_0^1 \pi (2)^2 \, dx+\int_1^5 \pi(2)^2-\pi(\sqrt{x-1})^2 \, dx$$

Comment: If it helps to clear it up, or makes a difference to your answer, the area we are talking about is [GRAPH](http://i.snag.gy/g5qbg.jpg) So does this make a difference?

Comment: Yes, this integral matches with the image linked by your comment. You can ask me further if you want anything clarified.

Comment: I think I see what you did, you just split it up into 2 objects if I assumed correctly. Also could you help me with the question I ask (y=2, x=5) at the end of my main question. NOTE: The y=2, and x=5 are two separate questions, so in 1 question asked to revolve about y=2, and in the other anoe about x=5

Comment: For $y=2$, the integral is $$\int_0^1 \pi(2)^2 \, dx + \int_1^5 \pi(\sqrt{x-1})^2 \, dx$$ For $x=5$, the integral is $$\int_0^2 \pi(5)^2 - \pi(y^2+1)^2 \, dy$$

Comment: Thank you very much! I really appreciate it!

Comment: Also last one if you have time for it:

Find the volume of the solid formed with cross sections that are squares perpendicular to the y-axis

Comment: Oops, I made a mistake with a radius: for $y=2$, the integral is actually $$\int_0^1 \pi(2)^2 \, dx + \int_1^5 \pi(\color{red}{2-\sqrt{x-1}})^2 \, dx.$$But the integral for $x=5$ is correct.

Comment: For the one with the square cross-sections perpendicular to the $y$-axis, we must find volume by integrating with respect to the variable $y$. Think about finding $A(y)=s^2$, where $s$ is a side of the square. The side is $s=y^2+1$ for $0 \le y \le 2$, so we have $A(y)=s^2=(y^2+1)^2$. Then find $$V=\int_0^2 A(y) \, dy=\int_0^2 (y^2+1)^2 \, dy.$$

Comment: Oh ok. Thanks for the correction! and advice, I will let you know what I come up with.

Comment: Sorry to disturb you, but I had done the same thing I had done for the revolving around the x-axis that I had for the y-axis. (In the original question I asked). So what would the volume of the solid be if it was generated about the y-axis?

Comment: If you revolve your solid about the $y$-axis, or equivalently $x=0$, then you will integrate with respect to the variable $y$. Your integral is $$V=\int_0^2 \pi(y^2+1)^2 \, dy,$$ where $y^2+1$ is your radius of a disk.

Comment: Thanks for the help, that is all I'll need tonight!